# Do something after template has fully rendered

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I've got an external template that calls to a JSON object to fill in details for divs. I'm struggling to get some jQuery to fire after all of the items have been added to the DOM (looking to use [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co)).

**Ideally, I'd like to get some support on how to get Isotope working - displaying items and clicking links to sort and filter, as well as some general Knockout help. I'm new to KO and I'm not even sure what I'm doing is best practice.**

***Here's the pertinent code (I'm not sure about getting a JSFiddle running with external templates - if you have any tips, I'm up for getting an example going!):***

If I change "afterAdd" to "afterRender", Isotope and it's filtering mechanisms will work - but it only renders one item - not the entire object.

**HTML**

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'itemList', foreach: sampleItems, afterAdd: renderIsotope }"></div>
```

**External Template**

```
<div data-bind='attr: { "class": "item " + type }'>
<div class="item-details">
    <span class="type" data-bind="text: type"></span>
    <span class="size" data-bind="text: size"></span>
    <span class="name" data-bind="text: name"></span>
    <!-- ko if: type === 'folder' -->
    <a href="#" class="changeFolderColor">Change Folder Color</a>
    <span class="folderColor" style="display: none" data-bind="text: backgroundColor"></span>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>

<!-- ko if: type !== 'folder' -->
<img data-bind="attr: { src: preview }" />
<!-- /ko -->
```

**Model**

```
var sampleItems = [    
{
    type: "image",
    size: "2482",
    name: "Robert",
    preview: "/images/placeholders/178x178-1.jpg",
    backgroundColor: "",
    id: "1"
}, ....
```

**ViewModel**

```
var itemsModel = function (items) {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(items, function (item) {
        return { type: item.type, size: item.size, name: item.name, preview: item.preview, backgroundColor: item.backgroundColor, id: item.id };
    }));
}
```

**Attempted "afterAdd" function**

```
var renderIsotope = function (elements) { 
// initialize isotope
$(".content .right").isotope({
    itemSelector: ".item",
    getSortData: {
        type: function ($elem) {
            return $elem.find(".type").text();
        },
        size: function ($elem) {
            return parseFloat($elem.find(".size").text());
        },
        name: function ($elem) {
            return $elem.find(".name").text();
        }
    }
});

// filter items when filter link is clicked
$('.item-filter a').click(function () {
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $(".content .right").isotope({ filter: selector });
    return false;
});

// sort items when sort link is clicked
$('.item-sort a').click(function () {
    // get href attribute, minus the '#'
    var sortName = $(this).attr('href').slice(1);
    $(".content .right").isotope({ sortBy: sortName });
    return false;
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Kncokout exposes afterrender binding for this purpose:

```
<div data-bind='template: { name: "personTemplate",
                        data: myData,
                        afterRender: myPostProcessingLogic }'> </div>
```

[more here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note_4_using_afterrender_afteradd_and_beforeremove)

Sorry haven't used isotope to help you with that

Comment: Thanks. My example code has afterAdd, but I've also tried afterRender. Also, about not having used Isotope, I don't think it's a case of that specific plugin. It's running a function in general.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the custom binding I'm using. This requires your viewModel to have an afterInit function. This fires when the applyBindings is called, or when Knockout binds the template.
The View model needs a function named afterInit:
Using the Revealing Module Pattern:

```
myViewModel = function(){
  var afterInitDone = false,
      afterInit = function(){
          // this fires from the custom afterInit binding below
          // set afterInitDone, so if it fires again, we ignore it in the custom binding
          afterInitDone = true;
      };

  return {
    AfterInit: afterInit
  };
};
ko.bindingHandlers.afterInit = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext)      
    {
        //Possible place for the draggables when creating the Editor tool
        //$(element).draggable({ containment: "#content", scroll: false });
        'use strict';
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        'use strict';
        // don't run again if it has already been called
        if (viewModel.afterInitDone !== undefined) {
           if (!viewModel.afterInitDone) {
               viewModel.AfterInit();
           }
        } else {
            viewModel.AfterInit();
        }
    }
};
```

Then I just bind to it in the html:  `<div data-bind="afterInit: true">`

See note 4: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "This requires your viewModel to have an afterInit function." ?

Comment: I added a section to my answer. Since the custom binding calls the AfterInit function on the view model, the view model the UI is bound to needs to implement this function.